# Swift Node.js Stripe Alamofire - Retrieve Connect Account

Tags: node.js, swift, stripe-payments

Looking for help on how to retrieve Stripe Connected Account Data. With my current code that is provided the only account I am able to retrieve is the main account that other users will connect too. I have gone through the stripe documentation and it seems like I am doing everything right yet it is strange I only get back the main account no matter how I try to call other connected accounts. These are also test connect accounts if this makes a difference. Also, the account that is provided in string format like `["account": "acct_1NTBUJPxUIDTXnbA"]` this is not the main account it is a test account that should get data pulled and has a completed profile.

**Swift Call**

```
static func getAccountData(accountID: String, completion: @escaping(Bool?) -> Void)  { //url, Error
    let parameters: [String:Any] = ["account": "acct_1NTBUJPxUIDTXnbA"]
    let url = "https://us-central1-shoppeer-e7270.cloudfunctions.net/getAccount"
    
    AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: [:]).responseJSON { response in
            guard let dict = response.value as? [String: Any]? else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
            
            guard let dict2 = dict?["body"] as? [String: Any] else {
                return completion(nil)
            }
            
            guard let _ = dict2["success"] as? String? else {
                if let failure = dict2["failure"] as? String {
                    return completion(nil)
                }
                return
            }
        }
}
```

**Node.js**

```
exports.getAccount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
const data = req.body;
const accountID = data.account;
var response = {}

stripe.accounts.retrieve(
accountID.stripeAccount,
function(err, account) {
  if (err) {
    response.body = {failure: err.message}
    return res.send(response)
  }

  response.body = {success: account}
  return res.send(response)
}
);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code to retrieve the Account id of the connected account should be

```
const account = await stripe.accounts.retrieve(
  accountID.stripeAccount
);
```

Your code has formatting issues.

```
stripe.accounts.retrieve(
accountID.stripeAccount,
function(err, account) { //here
  if (err) {
    response.body = {failure: err.message}
    return res.send(response)
  }

  response.body = {success: account}
  return res.send(response)
}
);
```

If that was a copypaste issue, you should log `accountID.stripeAccount` before you retrieve the account to validate if there's actually a value being passed in.

Comment: I am looking to retrieve the connected accounts full details. Just saying to give more of an understanding.

Comment: Also, the problem isn't that the call isn't being made. The issue is that the main account is always being called which the "business" that the vendors using stripe connect on-boarding sign up too. Instead of calling the actual test connect accounts data.